# Breezejs SaveChanges: custom nodejs SaveResult

Tags: node.js, mongoose, breeze

Is there an example showing the structure of the SaveResult object. I'm working with nodeJS and Mongoose on the back-end; thus I would like to manually construct that object and return it back to breezeJS.

Answer (score 0):

The SaveResult structure is defined in the api docs as the result of the *EntityManager.saveChanges* method: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges

Note that the SaveResult structure is actually processed thru the appropriate 'dataService' library (i.e. breeze.dataService.mongo or breeze.dataService.webApi) 'saveChanges' method before being passed onto the EntityManager.

Comment: I have noticed that facility; But the thing is that I'm using mongoose on the back end so I don't know whether it's possible to use breeze.tadaService.mongo library; So that's why I'm planning to construct it myself.

Comment: Use the Breeze mongodb dataservice adapter as a guide to writing your client-side adapter and the "breeze.server.node" files (starting [here](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node/blob/master/breeze-mongodb/breeze-mongodb.js)) as guide to writing your server code.